# Regex search with limited new lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following text:

```
                                KN_Divers_Blau |  -6.429897   8.010333    -0.80   0.422    -22.14101     9.28122
                                   Ind_ROA_Ave |   .3407456   .3389998     1.01   0.315    -.3241539    1.005645
                              Ind_Tobin_Q1_Ave |  -.5065654   .2104229    -2.41   0.016    -.9192797   -.0938511
                                Ind_Growth_Ave |  -1.404911   1.852805    -0.76   0.448    -5.038922    2.229101
                                       Pat_Dum |  -18.31015   5.452194    -3.36   0.001    -29.00385   -7.616457
                                               |
                                          year |
                                         1981  |  -5.575117   2.805975    -1.99   0.047    -11.07863   -.0715993
                                         1982  |  -6.171125   5.447273    -1.13   0.257    -16.85517    4.512919
                                         1983  |   -11.8282    8.84588    -1.34   0.181    -29.17812    5.521726
                                         1984  |  -20.39602   11.73682    -1.74   0.082    -43.41611    2.624069
                                         1985  |   -23.7097   14.29652    -1.66   0.097    -51.75028    4.330874
                                         1986  |  -29.43432   16.51849    -1.78   0.075    -61.83297    2.964339
                                         1987  |  -35.30922    18.5138    -1.91   0.057    -71.62137    1.002936
                                         1988  |  -49.09056   19.95166    -2.46   0.014    -88.22289   -9.958242
                                         1989  |  -53.98487   21.88913    -2.47   0.014    -96.91725   -11.05248
                                         1990  |  -67.58938   23.41111    -2.89   0.004    -113.5069   -21.67185
                                         1991  |  -78.59984   25.52294    -3.08   0.002    -128.6594   -28.54026
                                         1992  |  -88.89806   28.22778    -3.15   0.002    -144.2628   -33.53332
                                         1993  |  -98.40131   31.35391    -3.14   0.002    -159.8975   -36.90512
                                         1994  |   -102.953   33.25041    -3.10   0.002    -168.1689   -37.73712
                                         1995  |  -116.2812   37.25681    -3.12   0.002     -189.355   -43.20726
                                         1996  |  -118.0298   38.76035    -3.05   0.002    -194.0527   -42.00698
                                         1997  |  -118.4325    38.4338    -3.08   0.002    -193.8149   -43.05017
                                         1998  |  -123.8912   37.96394    -3.26   0.001     -198.352   -49.43038
                                         1999  |  -128.3908   39.44807    -3.25   0.001    -205.7626   -51.01913
                                         2000  |  -133.2699   40.31404    -3.31   0.001    -212.3401   -54.19972
                                         2001  |   -126.159   37.63045    -3.35   0.001    -199.9658   -52.35232
                                         2002  |  -119.8247   36.05833    -3.32   0.001    -190.5479   -49.10146
                                         2003  |  -109.2157   34.54755    -3.16   0.002    -176.9758   -41.45563
                                         2004  |  -114.1801   33.58204    -3.40   0.001    -180.0465   -48.31378
                                         2005  |          0  (omitted)
                                               |
                                         _cons |  -187.8645   62.81122    -2.99   0.003    -311.0597   -64.66936
                                         
                                         
                             KN_Divers_Blau |   -6.57637   8.068413    -0.82   0.415     -22.4014    9.248663
                                Ind_ROA_Ave |   .3641781   .3411348     1.07   0.286    -.3049088    1.033265
                           Ind_Tobin_Q1_Ave |  -.5070564   .2105863    -2.41   0.016    -.9200911   -.0940217
                             Ind_Growth_Ave |  -1.424116   1.871656    -0.76   0.447    -5.095101    2.246869
                                    Pat_Dum |  -18.51642   5.463958    -3.39   0.001    -29.23319   -7.799652
                                            |
                                       year |
                                      1981  |  -4.660021   2.721933    -1.71   0.087    -9.998702     .678659
                                      1982  |  -5.557028   5.497126    -1.01   0.312    -16.33885    5.224794
                                      1983  |  -10.63977   8.795378    -1.21   0.227    -27.89063    6.611104
                                      1984  |  -18.76668   11.39263    -1.65   0.100     -41.1117    3.578331
                                      1985  |  -23.61831   14.32697    -1.65   0.099    -51.71861    4.481984
                                      1986  |  -29.10203   16.61986    -1.75   0.080     -61.6995    3.495445
                                      1987  |  -34.29028   18.46377    -1.86   0.063    -70.50431    1.923745
                                      1988  |  -48.44084   19.75174    -2.45   0.014    -87.18104    -9.70065
                                      1989  |  -54.73721   22.04372    -2.48   0.013    -97.97281   -11.50162
                                      1990  |  -67.16001   23.65404    -2.84   0.005     -113.554   -20.76601
                                      1991  |  -77.92565   25.97627    -3.00   0.003    -128.8744   -26.97694
                                      1992  |  -88.53438   28.49949    -3.11   0.002     -144.432   -32.63673
                                      1993  |  -97.72113   31.57967    -3.09   0.002    -159.6601   -35.78213
                                      1994  |  -102.3819   33.38187    -3.07   0.002    -167.8557   -36.90815
                                      1995  |  -115.8907   37.23702    -3.11   0.002    -188.9258   -42.85566
                                      1996  |  -118.6755   39.02702    -3.04   0.002    -195.2214   -42.12961
                                      1997  |   -118.675   38.75563    -3.06   0.002    -194.6886   -42.66145
                                      1998  |   -124.622   38.53307    -3.23   0.001    -200.1991   -49.04492
                                      1999  |  -128.1722   39.91359    -3.21   0.001    -206.4569   -49.88741
                                      2000  |  -133.1516    40.6607    -3.27   0.001    -212.9017   -53.40144
                                      2001  |  -126.7362   38.51777    -3.29   0.001    -202.2833   -51.18914
                                      2002  |  -119.7739   36.83191    -3.25   0.001    -192.0145   -47.53344
                                      2003  |  -108.5075   34.97694    -3.10   0.002    -177.1097   -39.90524
                                      2004  |  -111.8748   33.35352    -3.35   0.001    -177.2929   -46.45662
                                      2005  |          0  (omitted)
                                            |
                                      _cons |   -178.691   61.08993    -2.93   0.003    -298.5101   -58.87189
```

And am looking for a regex expression that removes all the years, so the output would like something this:

```
                                KN_Divers_Blau |  -6.429897   8.010333    -0.80   0.422    -22.14101     9.28122
                                   Ind_ROA_Ave |   .3407456   .3389998     1.01   0.315    -.3241539    1.005645
                              Ind_Tobin_Q1_Ave |  -.5065654   .2104229    -2.41   0.016    -.9192797   -.0938511
                                Ind_Growth_Ave |  -1.404911   1.852805    -0.76   0.448    -5.038922    2.229101
                                       Pat_Dum |  -18.31015   5.452194    -3.36   0.001    -29.00385   -7.616457
                                               |
                                               |
                                         _cons |  -187.8645   62.81122    -2.99   0.003    -311.0597   -64.66936
                                         
                                         
                             KN_Divers_Blau |   -6.57637   8.068413    -0.82   0.415     -22.4014    9.248663
                                Ind_ROA_Ave |   .3641781   .3411348     1.07   0.286    -.3049088    1.033265
                           Ind_Tobin_Q1_Ave |  -.5070564   .2105863    -2.41   0.016    -.9200911   -.0940217
                             Ind_Growth_Ave |  -1.424116   1.871656    -0.76   0.447    -5.095101    2.246869
                                    Pat_Dum |  -18.51642   5.463958    -3.39   0.001    -29.23319   -7.799652
                                            |
                                            |
                                      _cons |   -178.691   61.08993    -2.93   0.003    -298.5101   -58.87189
```

I'm extremely new to regex, and have tried searching for the following and replace it with nothing in Notepad++:

```js
year.*[\n].*1981.*[\n].*2005
```

The problem is it finds all the values in between the first years columns and the second one and removes everything in between.

Is there a way to have the search term find each years column once? (So in my example, it would find and replace the years column twice in total)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^\s*year.*(?:[\r\n]+\s*\d{4}\b.*)*[\r\n]+
```

..and replace with an empty string.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lpV41h/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `^` Beginning of line.
- `\s*` Match zero or more whitespace characters.
- `year.*` Match "year" followed by any number of characters.
- `(?:` Start of a non-capturing group.

  - `[\r\n]+` Match one or more line-break character.
  - `\s*` Match zero or more whitespace characters.
  - `\d{4}\b.*` Match four digits followed by any number of characters.
- `)` Close the non-capturing group.
- `*` Match zero or more occurrences of the previous group.
- `[\r\n]+` Match one or more line-break character.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and explanations!